# Connecting to local DB while running docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, sequelpro

I am running an app from a docker container and at some point, I had Sequel Pro connected to my local DB but since reinstalling Sequel Pro, I haven't had luck connecting back to my local DB.  Where would I find the IP/port to use for this?  I tried connecting to 127.0.0.1 and also tried using the IP address listed in `docker inspect (container name)` to no avail.

Comment: Is the database running directly on the host, or in a sibling container?

Comment: it's a sibling container.

Comment: If it's running in a container, do `docker exec -it container-name /bin/bash` where container-name is the container name listed in `docker ps`

Comment: @nootdev then what though? I want to be connect to the DB on Sequel Pro again.  I had it but lost the settings because I had to uninstall the program a few weeks ago.

Comment: You need to expose the port locally then, if you're using, you can do this by using `EXPOSE 3306` in your `DockerFile`. One the port is exposed, you should be able to connect to it via `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

If you address `localhost` (or `127.0.0.1`) inside your container you refer to the `localhost` inside the container, not the system.

You can use [docker networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/). If you run the container in the same network (manually adding or with a compose file) you can address like `service name:port` inside the network. Ports does not have published outside for this (but useful if you want to rech your DB from your system).

A alternativ way is to run your container in network mode `host`. In this case you run on the network interface of the docker deamon und can use `localhost`. But you lose some of your isolation.